# Array of Custom Model is Nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to parse data from Firebase and my data object looks like this in JSON form:

```
"Things" : {
    "Blah1" : {
      "Id" : 1,
      "Location" : [ {
        "DownVote" : 1,
        "Latitude" : 42.36455,
        "Longitude" : 71.05796,
        "Time" : "rerwr",
        "UpVote" : 1
      }, {
        "DownVote" : 3,
        "Latitude" : 13.454,
        "Longitude" : 213.343,
        "Time" : "dfsadf",
        "UpVote" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
```

My `ThingModel` looks like this:

```
public class ThingModel {
    private var _id: Int!
    private var _locationArray:[LocationModel]!
    var id: Int {
        return _pokedexId
    }

    var locations: [LocationModel] {
        return _locationArray
    }

    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let id = dictionary["Id"] as? Int {
            _id = id
        }
        if let locations = dictionary["Location"] as? [LocationModel] {
            _locationArray = locations
        }
    }
}
```

And my `LocationModel` Looks like this:

```
private var Latitude: Double!
    private var Longitude: Double!
    private var UpVotes: Int!
    private var DownVotes: Int!
    private var Time: String!
    private var ModelKey: String!

    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Latitude, Longitude)
        return coordinate
    }

    var upVotes: Int {
        return UpVotes
    }

    var downVotes: Int {
        return DownVotes
    }

    var time: String {
        return Time
    }

    init(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self._modelKey = key
        if let latitude = dictionary["Latitude"] as? Double {
            self.Latitude = latitude
        }
        if let longitude = dictionary["Longitude"] as? Double {
            self.Longitude = longitude
        }
        if let downVotes = dictionary["DownVote"] as? Int {
            self.DownVotes = downVotes
        }
        if let upVotes = dictionary["UpVote"] as? Int {
            self.UpVotes = upVotes
        }
        if let time = dictionary["Time"] as? String {
            self.Time = time
        }
    }
```

The problem is, is that when I try calling the `locations` array in a for loop, the array is seen as null.

Here is the code:

```
_REF_BASE.child("Things").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]{
            for snap in snapshots {
                if let dict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let thingObject = thingModel(lobbyKey: key, dictionary: pokeDict)
                    for location in thingObject.locations {
                        let coord = location.locationCoordinate
                        let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
                        self.pinArray.append(pin)
                        pin.coordinate = coord
                        pin.title = thingObject.name
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

To recap, my `LocationModel` array is being returned as nil, and I don't know why.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `LocationModel` is `nil` because your `dictionary["Location"]` that's used to create it must also be `nil`.

Comment: And you really, really should avoid using implicitly-unwrapped optionals unless they're absolutely necessary (which is usually not the case) or idiomatic, like `@IBOutlet`s.

Comment: @NRitH Yes I understand that, but how do I get around that?

Comment: The Json at the top of the question is the json expoted from Firebase, so i'm fairly certain the array of `Location` is not nil

Comment: Where do you retrieve the data from firebase?  Are you trying to access the data before the asynchronous fetch is complete?

Comment: @Paulw11 The for loop is inside a `observeEventType` call, which I have verified is returning a proper dictionary and key

Comment: Can you show that code. When I see "return array" and asynchronous fetch is involved it makes my spidey sense tingle

Comment: Yup, just edited the question with that code

Comment: That code doesn't do anything with an array of `ThingModel`

Comment: Also, your ThingModel is initialised with `pokedict`. Shouldn't it be `dict`?

Comment: well i initialize the `ThingModel`, which should retrieve the array of `Location` right? And yes, it should be dict, but that isn't the problem

Comment: Ok. I follow you now. The conditional downcast to locations in your init will fail, since `dictionary["Location"]` will be `[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]`. You need to iterate this array and create `LocationModel` instances from the dictionaries. It won't happen automatically from a simple downcast

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what I figured. do you mind proposing an answer that I could try. I have tried this but have had ill results. Maybe i am just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to first get the array of "Location" dictionaries and then iterate through them and initialize the `LocationModel` object with the dictionary & key values. Casting to `[LocationModel]` will not automatically initialize `LocationModel` objects for you.

Here is a sample initializer for `ThingModel` which would initialize your LocationModel array appropriately,

```
init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    if let things = dictionary["Things"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        if let blah = things["Blah1"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let id = blah["Id"] as? Int {
                _id = id
            }

            if let locations = blah["Location"] as? [AnyObject] {
                var locationModelArray: [LocationModel] = []
                for location in locations {
                    locationModelArray.append(LocationModel(key: "key", dictionary: location as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>))
                }

                _locationArray = locationModelArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this doesn't work, it runs into the same issue

Comment: Via the debugger, it doesn't make it pass this if statement

`if let locations = dictionary["Location"] as? [AnyObject] {`

Comment: Can you explain the error you get? "It doesn't work" won't help to resolve the issue. I tried this with the JSON you provided and I could see the array populated.

Comment: Can you include the exact dictionary that you pass to `ThingModel` initializer?

Comment: The dictionary is represented by the Json from above. I am grabbing that dictionary from Firebase with this line `if let pokeDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {`, which does return the correct number of key val pairs

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post the JSON string you have in `pokeDict`. Any parsing is dependent on the format of the JSON it is supplied with. I still doubt that the JSON could be of different format or the keys in that json is different from what we use as subscript strings.

Comment: This solution does work, but wouldn't this be extremely inefficient?

Comment: If you think the nested `if let` is inefficient, you could use 3rd party JSON parsing libraries like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which allows you to skip nesting of `if let` statements and access JSON with subscripts. But your models need to be initialized manually with appropriate data.